# PHP - Setting variable to 0 at beginning of foreach loop not resetting for subsequent loops

Tags: php, variables, foreach

## Original Post

Writing a quick and dirty dump of a database in printable format -- General structure of the DB includes a "customers" table, with corresponding "orders" table. Here's the code in question:

```
(Previous Code)

<tbody align="center">
            <?php foreach ($result1 as $c): ?>
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $c['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['lastname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['firstname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c['notes']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php foreach ($result2 as $p): ?>
                        <?php if ($p['customer_id'] == $c['id']): ?>
                            <?php if ($i > 0){echo '$i counter: '.$i.'<br />';} ?> <!-- added the "'$i counter: '.$i" portion for debugging -->
                            <?php foreach ($types as $t): ?>
                                <?php if ($t['id'] == $p['shirt_type_id']){echo '<strong>Type:</strong> '.$t['type_name'];} ?>
                            <?php endforeach; foreach ($sizes as $s): ?>
                                <?php if ($s['id'] == $p['size_id']){echo '  <strong>Size:</strong> '.$s['size_name'];} ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php echo '  <strong>Quantity:</strong> '.$p['qty']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>

(Further Code)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that where there are multiple "orders" for a customer (i.e. they ordered multiple different types of t-shirts for their order), that the subsequent orders start on a new line within the cell. Using this code, I get output as shown (including the debug):

Photo: [Output of full script using dev/test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLky1.png)
 --- As you can see, my $i variable is incrementing by 1 in each iteration of the $result1 loop, although the first thing it should be doing in each passthrough of the loop is setting $i to 0. What gives? Thanks.

## Edit: (For Dave & Aniket)

I re-wrote the script as per your suggestions, putting the php in one block:

```
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Grad Cup T-Shirt Order Listing</h3>
    <table align="center" border="1.0px">
        <thead>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Products Ordered</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
            <?php foreach ($result1 as $c) //$result1 is an array of customer information for each order
            {
                $i = 0;
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['id'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['lastname'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['firstname'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['notes'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        foreach ($result2 as $p) //$result2 is an array of individual shirt purchases, with a 'customer_id' index, associating it with a $result1 line.
                        {
                            if ($p['customer_id'] == $c['id']) //Check to see that individual shirt order ($p) is associated with the current customer ($c)
                            {
                                ## Break to new line within cell if second (or higher) entry
                                echo $i.'<br />'; // if ($i > 0) {echo '<br />';}
                                ## If the shirt type for the order equals the id of the shirt type list, print the type name
                                foreach ($types as $t)
                                {
                                    if ($t['id'] == $p['shirt_type_id']) {echo '<strong>Type:</strong> '.$t['type_name'];}
                                }
                                ## If the shirt size for the order equals the id of the shirt size list, print the size name
                                foreach ($sizes as $s)
                                {
                                    if ($s['id'] == $p['size_id']) {echo '  <strong>Size:</strong> '.$s['size_name'];}
                                }
                                ## Print the quantity of this shirt type/size for this order
                                echo '  <strong>Quantity:</strong> '.$p['qty'];
                            }
                            $i++; //Increment the $i counter, run the $result2 loop again, will print a <br> if there was another t-shirt associated with that customer.
                        }
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Still having the same problem. Here is the output: [New Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82p8B.png)

As you can see, the $i counter is not resetting with each new loop of $result1. As a result, if I was just to change the line where it evaluates $i back to `<br />`, each line after the first would have a unnecessary break. Thoughts?

Comment: Can not reproduce!

Comment: What additional code would you need? I mean, you can't connect to the DB, so I don't imagine that reproduction is possible. 

The key code lines are the line setting $i = 0 at the beginning of the $result1 loop, and the line where it produces a '<br />' output if $i > 0.

I'm just trying to figure out why $i isn't resetting to 0 at the beginning of the next $result1 foreach loop.

Comment: Take a look at https://ideone.com/Ut2T0Q

Comment: Check for this condition `if ($p['customer_id'] == $c['id']):` , looks like it's misbehaving for your `$i`.

Comment: Yeah, I see where the counter is resetting in your example, thank you for this. It just seems that $i is not resetting to 0 through the declaratory statement at the beginning of each $result1 loop. I know there's a lot of nested loops in my code, but I feel like the general structure is the same :/

Comment: this would be easier to read as 1 big block of PHP where you include the HTML in the echo statements, like `echo "<td>$c['notes']</td>";` or `echo '<td>'.$c['notes'].'</td>';`

Comment: @DaveS - I'll try re-writing it in that fashion and see if I'm still encountering the issue, thanks.

Comment: @ajd2598 It is resetting to `0`, there is a condition check `if($i > 0)`, remove that and use `echo $i` instead. It will print `0`.

Comment: @DaveS & Aniket -- Edited the code per your suggestions, still having same output issues, can you re-evaluate? Thanks!

Comment: @ajd2598 There is no problem with the code that you have posted. Just as a suggestion, take a break for a while, like 20-30 minutes. Then debug this. I am sure this is just a silly mistake, and dw this happens to all of us :)

Comment: Thanks, Aniket. This is just boggling me a bit, clearly the $i counter is not resetting, I just am not even sure how to approach debugging this.

Comment: Can you try to echo the $i variable after incrementing it. e.g. ($i++; echo $i;)

Comment: @jundrie Sure, that should be reflected in the current test output [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82p8B.png) -- For each row, you can see that the echoed $i is increasing, but I can also add that just after the increase per your suggestion.

Comment: @ajd2598 Try `var_dump($result1)`, there is a lot of probability that it contains only one array.

Comment: Fixed this, please see answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone,

I managed to fix it. I moved the $i++ to be within the innermost if loop, instead of outside of it, and for whatever reason, that did the trick, final (working) code is as follows:

```
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Grad Cup T-Shirt Order Listing</h3>
    <table align="center" border="1.0px">
        <thead>
            <th>Order #</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Products Ordered</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
            <?php foreach ($result1 as $c) //$result1 is an array of customer information for each order
            {
                $i = 0;
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['id'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['lastname'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['firstname'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$c['notes'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        foreach ($result2 as $p) //$result2 is an array of individual shirt purchases, with a 'customer_id' index, associating it with a $result1 line.
                        {
                            if ($p['customer_id'] == $c['id']) //Check to see that individual shirt order ($p) is associated with the current customer ($c)
                            {
                                ## Break to new line within cell if second (or higher) entry
                                echo $i.'<br />'; //if ($i > 0) {echo '<br />';}
                                ## If the shirt type for the order equals the id of the shirt type list, print the type name
                                foreach ($types as $t)
                                {
                                    if ($t['id'] == $p['shirt_type_id']) {echo '<strong>Type:</strong> '.$t['type_name'];}
                                }
                                ## If the shirt size for the order equals the id of the shirt size list, print the size name
                                foreach ($sizes as $s)
                                {
                                    if ($s['id'] == $p['size_id']) {echo '  <strong>Size:</strong> '.$s['size_name'];}
                                }
                                ## Print the quantity of this shirt type/size for this order
                                echo '  <strong>Quantity:</strong> '.$p['qty'];
                                $i++; //Increment the $i counter, run the $result2 loop again, will print a <br> if there was another t-shirt associated with that customer.
                            }
                          //The $i++ used to be here.
                        }
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Results in output as follows: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Ds5.png) Thanks to everyone that assisted me.

Comment: After two days, the system will let you accept this as the answer. If you do so, it will help others who read the question in future.

Comment: What? No! That can't happen. Are you serious?

Comment: Completely serious, for whatever reason, putting the $i++ within the if loop for `if ($p['customer_id'] == $c['id'])` fixed the problem.